# How to move directories based on the output of rhash (CRC32 check of .sfv) with bash/perl?

Tags: shell, files, scripting

My idea, is to move the CRC-check OK folders (albums) into a lets say "complete+CRC_OK" folder with a script once per day in cron. I would need to put the rhash command in a loop with number of directories something like this way:

```
rhash --check array_of_folders[loop_index]/*.sfv
```

After that if "Everything OK" appeares on the standard output as last line (tail -1), then move he folder into ../complete+CRC_OK.

Adding this scipt to crontab won't be an issue, but my scripting knowledge is currently not enough for this.

Comment: done:
#!/bin/bash

for dir in */; do
 cd "$dir"
 rhash --check *.sfv
 output=$(rhash --check *.sfv | tail -1)
 cd ..
 if [ "$output" == "Everything OK" ]
  then
   mv "$dir" ../complete+crcok
 fi
done

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/Downloads/complete
for dir in */; do
        cd "$dir"
        output=$(rhash --check *.sfv | tail -1)
        cd ..
        if [ "$output" == "Everything OK" ]
                then
                        mv "$dir" ../complete+crcok
        fi
done
```